# Data assignment error for dbms_xmldom.domdocument

Tags: oracle, domdocument, xmldom

I'm trying the example in the link below

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_packages_dbms_xmldom_xmlparser.htm

but I get errors on this line

v_doc  := dbms_xmldom.cument(v_variable);

how can I solve this problem

ORA-06550: satır 31, sütun 25:
PLS-00302: component 'CUMENT' must be declared
ORA-06550: satır 31, sütun 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Pretty clearly a mistake in that code. Did you try to work out what it might have been intended to be? [This](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmldom.htm#i1130640) looks a likely candidate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alex Poole is correct.

It is not `CUMENT`. It is `NEWDOMDOCUMENT`

Try with this: `V_DOC := DBMS_XMLDOM.NEWDOMDOCUMENT(V_VARIABLE);`

Thanks